# problem on intersecting circles

Tags: geometry, circles

If two non-congruent circles with centres $A$ and $B$ intersect at $P$ and $Q$, then prove that among all lines drawn through $P$ and terminated by the circumference of two circles, the line which is parallel to $AB$ is the greatest.

Comment: First, I am not sure I know what this means. Second, is this homework and what have you tried?

Comment: I think the question is, let $A,B$ be circles, let them intersect at $C$ (and possibly at one more point). Consider all the line segments that go through $C$ and are contained in $A\cup B$. Prove that the longest one is the one parallel to the line joining the centers of the circle. Now: where does this problem come from? Why does it interest you? What ideas do you have about how to start to solve it?

Comment: Line contained in $A\cup B$? Still too sloppy for my taste, @GerryMyerson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: The segments in question have length $|\overline{PQ}|\cos\gamma$, where $\overline{PQ}$ is the segment parallel to the "line of centers", and $\gamma$ is the inclination from parallel; the length is clearly maximized when $\gamma = 0$.

---

Long answer ...

Let $\bigcirc A$ (of radius $a$) and $\bigcirc B$ (of radius $b$) intersect at $C$ (at distance $c$ from $\overline{AB}$). Let $\overline{PQ}$ be the segment through $C$, parallel to $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, with $P$ on $\bigcirc A$ and $Q$ on $\bigcirc B$. Let $\overline{RQ}$ be some other segment through $C$, with $R$ on $\bigcirc A$ and $S$ on $\bigcirc B$. (We'll take $\angle CRP$ to be non-obtuse, so that $\angle CSQ$ is non-acute. The argument is similar the other way around.)

Define

$$\alpha := \frac{1}{2} \angle CAP \qquad\qquad 
\beta := \frac{1}{2} \angle CBQ \qquad \qquad 
\gamma := \angle PCR = \angle QCS$$

[image: Double chords]

Note that
$$a \cos\alpha = b \cos \beta = c$$

Now, the Inscribed Angle Theorem gives us
$$\angle CRP = \alpha \qquad \text{and} \qquad \angle CSQ = 180^\circ - \beta \quad\to\quad \angle QSQ^\prime = \beta$$

and the Law of Sines provides

$$\frac{|\overline{PR}|}{\sin\gamma} = \text{diameter of}\; \bigcirc A = 2 a \qquad \frac{|\overline{QS}|}{\sin\gamma} = \text{diameter of}\; \bigcirc B = 2 b$$

Let $\overline{P^\prime Q^\prime}$ be the projection of $\overline{PQ}$ into $\overleftrightarrow{RS}$. We prove that $|\overline{P^\prime Q^\prime}| = |\overline{RS}|$ by showing $|\overline{P^\prime R}| = |\overline{Q^\prime S}|$:

$$|\overline{P^\prime R}| = |\overline{PR}| \cos \alpha = 2 a \sin \gamma \cos\alpha = 2 c \sin\gamma = 2 b\sin\gamma \cos\beta = |\overline{QS}|\cos\beta = |\overline{Q^\prime S}|$$

Consequently,

$$|\overline{RS}| = |\overline{P^\prime Q^\prime}| = |\overline{P^\prime C}| + |\overline{Q^\prime C}| = |\overline{PC}|\cos\gamma + |\overline{QC}|\cos\gamma = |\overline{PQ}|\cos\gamma$$

so that $|\overline{RS}|$ is maximized when $\gamma = 0$; that is, when $\overline{RS}$ coincides with $\overline{PQ}$. QED.

Comment: It took me a moment to figure out that for $\gamma=90°$ your answer of zero is indeed correct. I had somehow assumed that in this case, the correct answer should be the distance between the two points of intersection. But $S=C$ corresponds to the situation where $RS$ is a tangent to $\bigcirc B$ and intersects $\bigcirc A$ in a point $R$ which is not the other intersection point. As $R$ moves from that situation to the point of intersection, $S$ travels down the inner arc of $\bigcirc B$ to that same point, so eventually the length is indeed zero, just as the cosine computes it. Good to know!

Comment: great answer, i have one doubt; why is PR = 2a $sin \gamma$

Comment: @Aditya_math: As noted, "... the [Law of Sines](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofSines.html) provides ..."

Comment: oh yes , sorry, i forgot about the extended version. Thanks for such a quick reply! Cheers!